# Building a stadium with the Ethereum technology

Tags: blockchain

[Hristo Botev Stadium](https://www.google.bg/search?q=hristo%20botev%20stadium&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS5r2ugazXAhVBJ8AKHdV1CAIQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=1069)

Due to developments initiated by a group of politicians and oligarchy with alleged ties to the mafia, the construction of the new Hristo Botev stadium has been stopped since 2014. For four years, the most famous stadium in Plovdiv has been left at semi-finalized state.

Since 2014 the fans of the club,united in an official organizarion, own the club and the respective concession contract related to the Hristo Botev stadium.

Naturally, fans are looking for a way to finance the finalization of the stadium. Therefore, I would like to ask if there is a way to finance the completion of the stadium via the Ethereum technology?
Regards,
Teodor

Comment: The ethereum.org site provide an example how to create a crowdsale to raise funds for a project https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale. In your case the most difficult issue is not of the technology but of the lack of good governance/project management.